# Excel VBA 2010 array max limit?

Tags: excel, vba

I searched many sources but cannot find anywhere the max possible rows and columns an array can store in Excel VBA 2010. I need to perform calculations on array of at least 30,000 - 40,000 rows and 10-12 columns. Will there be any compatibility risk across machines on which code will be run?

Comment: Limited by available memory only.

Comment: All you need to do is search for [Data Type Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528(v=office.14).aspx).  If you don't exceed the limits shown there, you will be limited by available memory.  For the maximum number of rows and columns, search for Excel Specifications.